# How can I set eclipse to generate widgets in R class automatically?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in android.
I have a problem with my eclipse:

When I add a widget such as textView or Button to xml file it is **not generated in R class** even when I **clean the project** or **Build the project**. (There is no error in xml file).
The only way to generate it in R class is **Running the project**. immediately after running it would be generated.

I saw in some instructions; when we choose *Build automatically* under *project* tab, the widgets generated immediately after creation. But my eclipse doesn't.
How can I fix the problem?
Sorry for lame question, I searched it and I didn't find any answer.

Thank you

Ho

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228856/how-to-generate-an-r-file-in-android <-- maybe this question help you

Comment: In eclips the R class is generated. the problem is the widgets that I added to the activity_main.xml are not added in R class unless I run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **drawable** image.
It can't have Uppercase letters.
Or you can delete the **ic_launcher**.
And also check your layout can't have Uppercase letters too.

Then reboot the eclipse and clear again.
Please try.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is still exist.